# polygon vertex to vertex distance calculation in arcobjects

Tags: arcobjects, distance, donut-polygons

I have polygon with multipart (donuts) I want to calculate vertex to vertex distance. I tried to get outer ring vertex to vertex distance and it is working. Could you please tell me how to get inner ring vertex to outer ring vertex distance?

```c#
IPolygon polygon = buld_F.Shape as IPolygon;
IPointCollection ppcol = polygon as IPointCollection;                   
                    for (int j = 0; j < ppcol.PointCount -1; j++)
                    {
                        IPoint pp = ppcol.get_Point(j);
                        IPoint pp2 = ppcol.get_Point(j + 1);
                        double xvalue2 = pp2.X;
                        double yvalue2 = pp2.Y;
                        double xvalue1 = pp.X;
                        double yvalue1 = pp.Y;
                        double dist = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(xvalue2 - xvalue1, 2) + Math.Pow(yvalue2 - yvalue1, 2));
                        double ptop_dist = dist * 100;
                        if (ptop_dist <= 20)
                        {
                            dt.Rows.Add(buld_F.OID, buld_F.Class.AliasName, tgid_val, xvalue2, yvalue2, "Vertex to Vertex distance < 20CM");
                        }                      
                    }
```

[image: Example image]

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem.

```
IPolygon4 polygon = buld_F.Shape as IPolygon4;
                    IGeometryBag exteriorRingGeometryBag = polygon.ExteriorRingBag;
                    IGeometryCollection exteriorRingGeometryCollection = exteriorRingGeometryBag as IGeometryCollection;
                    for (int i = 0; i < exteriorRingGeometryCollection.GeometryCount; i++)
                    {
                        IGeometry exteriorRingGeometry = exteriorRingGeometryCollection.get_Geometry(i);
                        IPointCollection exteriorRingPointCollection = exteriorRingGeometry as IPointCollection;
                        for (int j = 0; j < exteriorRingPointCollection.PointCount - 1; j++)
                        {
                            IPoint pp = exteriorRingPointCollection.get_Point(j);
                            IPoint pp2 = exteriorRingPointCollection.get_Point(j + 1);
                            double xvalue2 = pp2.X;
                            double yvalue2 = pp2.Y;
                            double xvalue1 = pp.X;
                            double yvalue1 = pp.Y;
                            double dist = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(xvalue2 - xvalue1, 2) + Math.Pow(yvalue2 - yvalue1, 2));
                            double ptop_dist = dist * 100;
                            if (ptop_dist <= 20)
                            {
                                dt.Rows.Add(buld_F.OID, buld_F.Class.AliasName, tgid_val, xvalue2, yvalue2, "Vertex to Vertex distance < 20CM");
                            }
                        }
                        IGeometryBag interiorRingGeometryBag = polygon.get_InteriorRingBag(exteriorRingGeometry as IRing);
                        IGeometryCollection interiorRingGeometryCollection = interiorRingGeometryBag as IGeometryCollection;
                        for (int k = 0; k < interiorRingGeometryCollection.GeometryCount; k++)
                        {
                            interiorRingGeometry = interiorRingGeometryCollection.get_Geometry(k);
                            IPointCollection interiorRingPointCollection = interiorRingPointCollection = interiorRingGeometry as IPointCollection;
                            for (int m = 0; m < interiorRingPointCollection.PointCount - 1; m++)
                            {
                                IPoint pp = interiorRingPointCollection.get_Point(m);
                                IPoint pp2 = interiorRingPointCollection.get_Point(m + 1);
                                double xvalue2 = pp2.X;
                                double yvalue2 = pp2.Y;
                                double xvalue1 = pp.X;
                                double yvalue1 = pp.Y;
                                double dist = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(xvalue2 - xvalue1, 2) + Math.Pow(yvalue2 - yvalue1, 2));
                                double ptop_dist = dist * 100;
                                if (ptop_dist <= 20)
                                {
                                    dt.Rows.Add(buld_F.OID, buld_F.Class.AliasName, tgid_val, xvalue2, yvalue2, "Vertex to Vertex distance < 20CM");
                                }
                            }
                        }
```